# Android Lollipop - read title of notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm just testing my app on Android 5.0 and I discover that I am no more able to get the RemoteViews from third party notifications to read its title and ticker text like I did in KitKat. The code I used successfully on KitKat is similar to this:

```
public static List<String> getText(Notification notification) {

    RemoteViews views = notification.contentView;
    if (views == null)
        return null;
    else  {
        ...
    }
}
```

This function return me NULL so it isn't able to grab the entire contentView from the notification. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured out that the correct approach is to use AccesssibilityService for Android <= JELLY_BEAN_MR2 and to extend the NotificationListenerService for other newer versions.
In the new class, extension of NotificationListenerService, it is necessary to add the declaration `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.THE_OS_NAME_YOU_WANT)` on the top, to ensure that the following code will be executed just starting by that version of the OS.

It works like it should.

I hope it will help someone else.

Thank you anyway